# Регулярные выражения. Поиск слова в начале и в середине текста после пробела

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Можете подсказать какими регулярными выражениями я могу найти какое то слово целиком для примера мне надо найти слово "***дорога***"

> **Дорога** дальняя, **дорога** длинная ... долгаядорога вне куда.

Так вот в этом тексте надо найти первое слово так как оно идет в самом начале и третье слово которое идет после пробела а там где написано ***долгаядорога*** соответственно что бы вообще не искало.
Ну и что бы поиск мог соответствовать для такого примера

> Дальняя **дорога**, **дорога** длинная ... долгаядорога вне куда.

или

> Дальняя **дорога**, длинная **дорога** ... долгаядорога вне куда.

и последнее или и таких вариантов может быть наверное много

> Дальняя **дорога**, длиннаядорога ... долгая **дорога** вне куда.

Только в последнем варианте должно найти дорогу которая написана вторым и пятым словами ну а ***длиннаядорога*** игнорировать.

Уже неделю пытаюсь решить этот ребус сам =(

Comment: Может быть такая регулярка [`/\bдорога\b/gmui`](https://regex101.com/r/llT4Gd/1)

Comment: К сожалению она не очень как то хочет работать в JS

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант...

```
const re = /(?<=^|\s)дорога(?=$|\s|[,\.!?])/gi
alert('Дорога дальняя, дорога длинная ... долгаядорога вне куда.'.match(re))
alert('Дальняя дорога, дорога длинная ... долгаядорога вне куда.'.match(re))
alert('Дальняя дорога, длинная дорога... долгаядорога вне куда.'.match(re))
alert('Дальняя дорога, длиннаядорога ... долгая дорога вне куда.'.match(re))
```